# Subsetting one lost based on values of other list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Let say I have below two lists

```
List1 = [3,4,5,6,8,3,2,4,6,7,8,6]
List2 = [4, 7]
```

Now, based on the values of the second list, I want to extract the values of the first list. So trivially I would write

```
List1[List2[0] : List2[1]]
```

While it is fine, I want to make above line more concise. As you see I had to use the name `List2` twice in above line. But to maintain my overall writing style, I want to call `List2` only once as minimum number possible (perhaps)

Is there really any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(List1[slice(*List2)])
```

Prints:

```
[8, 3, 2]
```